What language is used in the QGIS expression builder?
I am learning to use QGIS and want to know which language to input in the expression builder.
I just want to know what to learn. The GIS stack exchange won't let my question be answered (because it involves coding?) so please help me!
I've had some success using input similar to SQL, but I don't know where to look up more info without knowing which language I need to use. Would I use Pyqgis, some specific form of SQL?

https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html

python. Here's the documentation https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html#id10

QGIS expresion bulider base on SQL mixed with Python. Some elements of SQL works, some elements of python also works, but not all. For example single qoute is for string, double qoute is for reference to field in atribute table.
For more information look for official documention for QGIS docs.qgis
